# ASP.NET Core 6 Angular Template Static Files 404

Tags: angular, visual-studio, asp.net-core

I create a clean project with the "ASP.NET Core with Angular" template in Visual Studio 2022 (v17.1.0). I add a folder called "images" to the "wwwroot" folder. I add an image called "logo.png" to the "images" directory. I add an image tag to the index.html file referencing the logo.png file. When I run the project the reference to the image returns a 404 error. I've tried referencing the file by "~/images/logo.png", "/images/logo.png", and "images/logo.png". I also ensured that "app.UseStaticFiles()" in included in my "Program.cs" file. I've read [this MS article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-6.0) and everything I'm doing seems in line with what they're doing. Others online seem to be having a similar issue, but not until they actually deploy the application. I can't get the image to show in debug mode from Visual Studio. I'm sure I missed something simple but usually the Visual Studio templates run great out of the box. Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Angular version is 13.0.1.

Comment: A coworker told me what the issue was. The ASP.NET Core 6.0 template uses a reverse proxy in development. You have to update the context constant in the proxy.config.js file to include anything you wish to be served under wwwroot. The context variable includes only "/weatherforecast" upon creation of the project. Hope this helps someone else.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how you did to resove the issue ?

Answer (score 0):

In proxy.conf.js you add your folders to "context" like so:

```
   [...code added by VS...]
 
   const PROXY_CONFIG = [
       {
          context: [
             "/images",
             "/scripts",
             "/styles"
          ],
          target: target,
          secure: false,
          headers: {
             Connection: "Keep-Alive"
          }
       }
    ]

    module.exports = PROXY_CONFIG
```

Any folder you want to the app to "see" should be added to the "context" property.